# Delaying a task in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

I'm receiving acceleration values from an external kit with my Smartphone. My primary goal is to detect a fall, and I'm using following algorithm to achieve this:

```
// Method to be triggered, when data is received over BLE interface
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
    data = parse(c);
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}


@Override
public String getDataString() {
    final float[] data = getData();
    return TiSensorUtils.coordinatesToString(data);
}

@Override
public float[] parse(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {    
    Integer x = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
    Integer y = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 1);
    Integer z = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 2);

    double X = x / 64.0;
    double Y = y / 64.0;
    double Z = -1 * z / 64.0;
    double G = Math.sqrt((X * X) + (Y * Y) + (Z * Z));
    double L = 1;                 

    if ((G > 1.3 || G < 0.7) && timerStatus.equals("OFF"))
    {           
        // I WANT THE DELAY HERE !!!!!!!!
        if ((Z < -0.9 && Z > -1.1 || (Z < 1.1 && Z > 0.9)) && (X < 0.3 && X > -0.3) && (Y < 0.3 && Y > -0.3))
        {
            cdt = new accCountDownTimer(4000, 1000);
            cdt.start();
            timerStatus = "ON";
            return new float[]{(float)X, (float)Y, (float)Z, (float)G, (float)L};                   
        }
    }       
        return new float[]{(float)X, (float)Y, (float)Z, (float)G};                 
}
```

I want a kind of task delay function just after the first "if" statement, but since I don't want to block the thread, Thread.Sleep(2000) will be useless in this case. I have succesfully implemented a corresponding algorithm in C#, where I used Task.delay(2000) for this purpose. Is there a similar method in java ?.

Comment: Try to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/4029941)

Answer (score 2):

```
    snoozeTimer.
    schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onSnoozeTimerExpiry();
                }
            });
        }
    }, snoozeDuration);
```

Comment: I want to return a float array just after the delay, but the Runnable is a void.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
new Handler().postDelayed(Runnable, delaytime);
```

**updated answer:**

you might want to do this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            data = parse(c);
        }
    }, delayMillis);
```

Comment: but the runnable returns a void(), and I have to return a float array

Comment: do everything on your "run()" method, implement a Runnable, and call everything inside run()

Comment: But still. I only want a part of my "parse()" method to be delayed. I  still have to return a float array in all cases, so it does not make sense to implement everything in a void method ?

Comment: if it was me I'd rearrange that, separate the first and second part, let the first part run normally and then do the delayed thing for the second part, you don't have to stick to that method as it is

Comment: Can you please show your proposal with example code ?

Comment: first i'll need your call to this method, to know how you manage your returned array (float[])